# WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raise unhandled exception ORA-01400

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am tring to import data from .CSV file to Oracle database. 
Once I run I get error

```
WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raise unhandled exception ORA-01400

declare 

   import_file text_io.file_type; 
   export_file text_io.file_type; 
   import_file_name varchar2(1000);
   export_file_name varchar2(1000);

   import_log_file text_io.file_type;
   import_log_file_name varchar2(1000);

  vec_importovano number;
   brojac number;
   brojac_redova number;
   linebuf varchar2(5000);

   p_rbr varchar2(10);
   p_polica varchar2(10);
   p_banka VARCHAR2(10);
   p_kontakt varchar2(10);

  kraj_fajla number;

begin
    brojac_redova:=0;

    import_file_name := :Global.Lokacija_prenosa||:import.naziv_fajla||:Global.Ekstenzija_prenosa;
    import_file := text_io.fopen(import_file_name,'r');

    delete from zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude where banka is not null;
    commit;

    kraj_fajla := 0;  
    while kraj_fajla = 0 loop
  begin     
    brojac_redova:=brojac_redova+1;
    text_io.get_line(import_file, linebuf);               

 if brojac_redova > 2 then

   p_polica:=substr(linebuf, 1, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);
   --message(p_polica);
   p_kontakt:=substr(linebuf, instr(linebuf,';',1,1)+1, instr(linebuf,';',1,2) - instr(linebuf,';',1,1)-1);

/*
If it has third semicolon then use your formula, string between 2 and 3. If it has only two semicolons then use from second to the end of string.
*/

   if instr(linebuf,';',1,3) > 0 then 
            p_banka := substr(linebuf, 
                            instr(linebuf,';',1, 2) + 1, 
                            instr(linebuf,';',1,3) - instr(linebuf,';',1,2)-1);
                           -- message(p_banka);

        else
          p_banka := substr(linebuf, 
                            instr(linebuf,';',1, 2) + 1);   
                            --message(p_banka);                     
        end if;  


        insert into ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE 
        (BROJ_POLICE,REDNI_BROJ,BROJ_PONUDE,BANKA)  
         values(
         p_polica,p_rbr,p_kontakt,p_banka);     
            commit;                   
                end if;



     EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN kraj_fajla := 1;         
     end;

end loop;  
     IF p_rbr IS NOT NULL THEN
   update zivot_trajni_nalog_ponude set redni_broj=rownum;
    end if;         
    text_io.fclose(import_file);
      message('Zavrseno prepisivanje fajla');

end;
```

Before I insert data into table I try to check if p_polica is NULL but this doesn't work. 
Since I don't have debugger in my IDE I could not check where mistake comes from.
Does anyone know where could be mistake I would be very thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description for ORA-01400 is "cannot insert NULL into (string)". You didn't give us the full text of the error message so I don't know what `(string)` might be, but it's probably a table name and field name - know which table and field could be important here.

I suspect that table `ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE` has a field which does not allow NULL values in it, and that you're not populating in your INSERT statement or for which the value you're providing is NULL. For example, you're putting the value of `p_rbr` into `ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE.REDNI_BROJ`, but `p_rbr` is never given a value and is therefore NULL. If `ZIVOT_TRAJNI_NALOG_PONUDE.REDNI_BROJ` has a NOT NULL constraint on it you'd get that error.